# Do these fountains have any purpose?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In deserts, you can find these fountains:

[image: Desert Fountain]

Do they serve any purpose at all, or are they just aesthetic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are known as [Desert Wells](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Generated_structures#Desert_well).

They have a 1/1000 chance to be generated in every desert chunk.

They stand no particular purpose, other than a source of water.

Comment: Seems obsolete in the screenshot since it is next to an ocean...

Comment: @PythonMaster Oceans are salty, wells are not.

Comment: No need to get salty about it...

Comment: Well, there are things that make the difference in salty&clear water, for example EnviroMine :)